# How to use multiple models with a single route in EmberJS / Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

From reading the docs, it looks like you have to (or should) assign a model to a route like so:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Post.find();
    }
});
```

What if I need to use several objects in a certain route? i.e. Posts, Comments and Users? How do I tell the route to load those?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**Last update forever**: I can't keep updating this. So this is deprecated and will likely be this way. here's a better, and more up-to-date thread [EmberJS: How to load multiple models on the same route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route)

**Update:** In my original answer I said to use `embedded: true` in the model definition. That's incorrect. In revision 12, Ember-Data expects foreign keys to be defined with a suffix ([link](https://github.com/opichals/emberjs-data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#revision-12)) `_id` for single record or `_ids` for collection. Something similar to the following:

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'string',
    body: 'string string string string...',
    author_id: 1,
    comment_ids: [1, 2, 3, 6],
    tag_ids: [3,4]
}
```

I have updated the fiddle and will do so again if anything changes or if I find more issues with the code provided in this answer.

---

**Answer with related models:**

For the scenario you are describing, I would rely on [associations](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_relationships) between models <s>(setting `embedded: true`)</s> and only load the `Post` model in that route, considering I can define a `DS.hasMany` association for the `Comment` model and `DS.belongsTo` association for the `User` in both the `Comment` and `Post` models. Something like this:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    posts: DS.hasMany('App.Post'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post'),
    author: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
});
```

This definition would produce something like the following:

[image: Associations between models]

With this definition, whenever I `find` a Post, I will have access to a collection of comments associated with that post, and the comment's author as well, and the user which is the author of the post, <s>since they are all embedded</s>. The route stays simple:

```
App.PostsPostRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Post.find(params.post_id);
    }
});
```

So in the `PostRoute` (or `PostsPostRoute` if you're using `resource`), my templates will have access to the controller's `content`, which is the `Post` model, so I can refer to the author, simply as `author`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/post">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <div>by {{author.fullName}}</div><hr />
    <div>
        {{body}}
    </div>
    {{partial comments}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_comments">
    <h5>Comments</h5>
    {{#each content.comments}}
    <hr />
    <span>
        {{this.body}}<br />
        <small>by {{this.author.fullName}}</small>
    </span>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/dDWdv/))

---

**Answer with non-related models:**

However, if your scenario is a little more complex than what you described, and/or *have* to use (or query) different models for a particular route, I would recommend to do it in [`Route#setupController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController). For example:

```
App.PostsPostRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Post.find(params.post_id);
    },
    // in this sample, "model" is an instance of "Post"
    // coming from the model hook above
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
        // the "user_id" parameter can come from a global variable for example
        // or you can implement in another way. This is generally where you
        // setup your controller properties and models, or even other models
        // that can be used in your route's template
        controller.set('user', App.User.find(window.user_id));
    }
});
```

And now when I'm in the Post route, my templates will have access to the `user` property in the controller as it was set up in `setupController` hook:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/post">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <div>by {{controller.user.fullName}}</div><hr />
    <div>
        {{body}}
    </div>
    {{partial comments}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_comments">
    <h5>Comments</h5>
    {{#each content.comments}}
    <hr />
    <span>
        {{this.body}}<br />
        <small>by {{this.author.fullName}}</small>
    </span>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/vF9S8/))

Comment: Thank you *so much* for taking the time to post that, I found it really useful.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe, really good post! Now my approach looks really naïve :)

Comment: The problem with your non-related models is that it doesn't accept promises like the model hook does, right?
Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you can adapt it in an easy way. Just wait for the promise to fulfill and only then set the model(s) as a variable of the controller

Comment: Other than iterating and displaying comments, it will be lovely if you could show an example of how someone might add an new comment into `post.comments`.

Comment: The syntax for specifying associations has changed since `Ember Data beta2` was released. It should now be `posts: DS.hasMany('post')` etc. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18588616/574190) for more details.

Comment: Ember-data will make [all relationships async before 1.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/18/the-road-to-ember-data-1-0.html) so your advice to use model relationships is probably not the best option anymore as it would make the controller deal with the promises (which is possible but painful IME). Perhaps you could edit your answer to promote your "non related models" solution?

Comment: This answer is superb.  Answered one of the nagging questions about the correct way to do such things in Ember for the longest time!

Comment: For associated models, in the route when I load root model and I want to load all the child model data before the controller is set up, how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 49):

Using `Em.Object` to encapsulate multiple models is a good way to get all data in `model` hook. But it can't ensure all data is prepared after view rendering.

Another choice is to use `Em.RSVP.hash`. It combines several promises together and return a new promise. The new promise if resolved after all the promises are resolved. And `setupController` is not called until the promise is resolved or rejected.

```
App.PostRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      post:     // promise to get post
      comments: // promise to get comments,
      user:     // promise to get user
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    // You can use model.post to get post, etc
    // Since the model is a plain object you can just use setProperties
    controller.setProperties(model);
  }
});
```

In this way you get all models before view rendering. And using `Em.Object` doesn't have this advantage.

Another advantage is you can combine promise and non-promise. Like this:

```
Em.RSVP.hash({
  post: // non-promise object
  user: // promise object
});
```

Check this to learn more about `Em.RSVP`: https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js

---

**But don't use `Em.Object` or `Em.RSVP` solution if your route has dynamic segments**

The main problem is `link-to`. If you change url by click link generated by `link-to` with models, the model is passed directly to that route. 
In this case the `model` hook is not called and in `setupController` you get the model `link-to` give you.

An example is like this:

The route code:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('/post/:post_id');
});

App.PostRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      post: App.Post.find(params.post_id),
      user: // use whatever to get user object
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    // Guess what the model is in this case?
    console.log(model);
  }
});
```

And `link-to` code, the post is a model:

```
{{#link-to "post" post}}Some post{{/link-to}}
```

Things become interesting here. When you use url `/post/1` to visit the page, the `model` hook is called, and `setupController` gets the plain object when promise resolved.

But if you visit the page by click `link-to` link, it passes `post` model to `PostRoute` and the route will ignore `model` hook. In this case `setupController` will get the `post` model, of course you can not get user.

So make sure you don't use them in routes with dynamic segments.

Comment: My answer applies to an earlier version of Ember & Ember-Data. This is a really good approach +1

Comment: Actually there is. if you want to pass model id instead of model itself to link-to helper, the model hook is always triggered.

Comment: This should be documented somewhere on the Ember guides (best practices or something). It's an important use case that I'm sure many people encounter.

Comment: If you are using `controller.setProperties(model);` do not forget to add these properties with default value to controller. Otherwise it will throw exception `Cannot delegate set...`

Answer (score 13):

For a while I was using `Em.RSVP.hash`, however the problem I ran into was that I didn't want my view to wait until all models were loaded before rendering. However, I found a great (but relatively unknown) solution thanks to the folks at [Novelys](http://www.novelys.com/blog/2014/07/07/ember-parallel-loading-of-several-resources.html) that involves making use of the [Ember.PromiseProxyMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html):

Let's say you have a view that has three distinct visual sections. Each of these sections should be backed by its own model. The model backing the "splash" content at the top of the view is small and will load quickly, so you can load that one normally:

Create a route `main-page.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('main-stuff');
    }
});
```

Then you can create a corresponding Handlebars template `main-page.hbs`:

```
<h1>My awesome page!</h1>
<ul>
{{#each thing in model}}
    <li>{{thing.name}} is really cool.</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
<section>
    <h1>Reasons I Love Cheese</h1>
</section>
<section>
    <h1>Reasons I Hate Cheese</h1>
</section>
```

So let's say in your template you want to have separate sections about your love/hate relationship with cheese, each (for some reason) backed by its own model. You have many records in each model with extensive details relating to each reason, however you'd like the content on top to render quickly. This is where the `{{render}}` helper comes in. You can update your template as so:

```
<h1>My awesome page!</h1>
<ul>
{{#each thing in model}}
    <li>{{thing.name}} is really cool.</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
<section>
    <h1>Reasons I Love Cheese</h1>
    {{render 'love-cheese'}}
</section>
<section>
    <h1>Reasons I Hate Cheese</h1>
    {{render 'hate-cheese'}}
</section>
```

Now you'll need to create controllers and templates for each. Since they're effectively identical for this example, I'll just use one.

Create a controller called `love-cheese.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin, {
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        var promise = this.store.find('love-cheese');
        if (promise) {
            return this.set('promise', promise);
        }
    }
});
```

You'll notice that we are using the `PromiseProxyMixin` here, which makes the controller promise-aware. When the controller is initialized, we indicate that the promise should be loading the `love-cheese` model via Ember Data. You'll need to set this property on the controller's `promise` property.

Now, create a template called `love-cheese.hbs`:

```
{{#if isPending}}
  <p>Loading...</p>
{{else}}
  {{#each item in promise._result }}
    <p>{{item.reason}}</p>
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

In your template, you'll be able to render different content depending on the state of promise. When your page initially loads, your "Reasons I Love Cheese" section will display `Loading...`. When the promise is loaded, it will render all the reasons associated for each record of your model.

Each section will load independently and not block the main content from rendering immediately.

This is a simplistic example, but I hope everyone else finds it as useful as I did.

If you're looking to do something similar for many rows of content, you may find the Novelys example above even more relevant. If not, the above should work fine for you.

Answer (score 8):

This might not be best practice and a naïve approach, but it shows conceptually how you would go about having on multiple models available on one central route:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var multimodel = Ember.Object.create(
      {
        posts: App.Post.find(),
        comments: App.Comments.find(),
        whatever: App.WhatEver.find()
      });
    return multiModel;
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    // now you have here model.posts, model.comments, etc.
    // as promises, so you can do stuff like
    controller.set('contentA', model.posts);
    controller.set('contentB', model.comments);
    // or ...
    this.controllerFor('whatEver').set('content', model.whatever);
  }
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: This approach is fine, just not taking too much advantage of Ember Data. For some scenarios where the models are not related, I'd got for something similar to this.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to all the other excellent answers, I created a mixin that combines the best solutions here into a simple and reusable interface.  It executes an `Ember.RSVP.hash` in `afterModel` for the models you specify, then injects the properties into the controller in `setupController`.  It does not interfere with the standard `model` hook, so you would still define that as normal.

Example use:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.AdditionalRouteModelsMixin, {

  // define your model hook normally
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('post', params.post_id);
  },

  // now define your other models as a hash of property names to inject onto the controller
  additionalModels: function() {
    return {
      users: this.store.find('user'), 
      comments: this.store.find('comment')
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the mixin:

```
App.AdditionalRouteModelsMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({

  // the main hook: override to return a hash of models to set on the controller
  additionalModels: function(model, transition, queryParams) {},

  // returns a promise that will resolve once all additional models have resolved
  initializeAdditionalModels: function(model, transition, queryParams) {
    var models, promise;
    models = this.additionalModels(model, transition, queryParams);
    if (models) {
      promise = Ember.RSVP.hash(models);
      this.set('_additionalModelsPromise', promise);
      return promise;
    }
  },

  // copies the resolved properties onto the controller
  setupControllerAdditionalModels: function(controller) {
    var modelsPromise;
    modelsPromise = this.get('_additionalModelsPromise');
    if (modelsPromise) {
      modelsPromise.then(function(hash) {
        controller.setProperties(hash);
      });
    }
  },

  // hook to resolve the additional models -- blocks until resolved
  afterModel: function(model, transition, queryParams) {
    return this.initializeAdditionalModels(model, transition, queryParams);
  },

  // hook to copy the models onto the controller
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.setupControllerAdditionalModels(controller);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16466427/2637573 is fine for related models. However, with recent version of Ember CLI and Ember Data, there is a simpler approach for unrelated models:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller,model);
    var model2 = DS.PromiseArray.create({
      promise: this.store.find('model2')
    });
    model2.then(function() {
      controller.set('model2', model2)
    });
  }
});
```

If you only want to retrieve an object's property for `model2`, use [DS.PromiseObject](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseObject.html) instead of [DS.PromiseArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller,model);
    var model2 = DS.PromiseObject.create({
      promise: this.store.find('model2')
    });
    model2.then(function() {
      controller.set('model2', model2.get('value'))
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I have a `post` edit route/view where I want to render all the existing tags in the DB so that the use can click to add them to the post being edited. I want to define a variable that represents an array/collection of these tags. Would the approach you used above work for this?

Comment: Sure, you would create a `PromiseArray` (e.g. "tags"). Then, in your template you would pass it to the selection element of the corresponding form.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to MilkyWayJoe's answer, thanks btw:

```
this.store.find('post',1)
```

returns

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'string',
    body: 'string string string string...',
    author_id: 1,
    comment_ids: [1, 2, 3, 6],
    tag_ids: [3,4]
};
```

author would be

```
{
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Joe',
    lastName: 'Way',
    email: 'MilkyWayJoe@example.com',
    points: 6181,
    post_ids: [1,2,3,...,n],
    comment_ids: [1,2,3,...,n],
}
```

comments

```
{
    id:1,
    author_id:1,
    body:'some words and stuff...',
    post_id:1,
}
```

...
I believe the link backs are important so that the full relationship is established. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `beforeModel` or `afterModel` hooks as these are always called, even if `model` is not called because you're using dynamic segments.

As per the [asynchronous routing](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_code-beforemodel-code-and-code-aftermodel-code) docs:

> The model hook covers many use cases for pause-on-promise transitions, but sometimes you'll need the help of the related hooks beforeModel and afterModel. The most common reason for this is that if you're transitioning into a route with a dynamic URL segment via {{link-to}} or transitionTo (as opposed to a transition caused by a URL change), the model for the route you're transitioning into will have already been specified (e.g. {{#link-to 'article' article}} or this.transitionTo('article', article)), in which case the model hook won't get called. In these cases, you'll need to make use of either the beforeModel or afterModel hook to house any logic while the router is still gathering all of the route's models to perform a transition.

So say you have a `themes` property on your `SiteController`, you could have something like this:

```
themes: null,
afterModel: function(site, transition) {
  return this.store.find('themes').then(function(result) {
    this.set('themes', result.content);
  }.bind(this));
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model);
  controller.set('themes', this.get('themes'));
}
```

Comment: I think using `this` inside the promise would give an error message. You could set `var _this = this` before the return and then do `_this.set(` inside the `then(` method to get the desired outcome