# Ember Data not finding model, while it is clearly there

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have as many others upgraded my ember app to the newest version of anything, but after having upgraded, my app is still not working.

I have simplified a lot, and it boils down to my route. My route is like this (as suggested in the transition guide):

```
App.BoxesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('box');
  }
});
```

Extremely simple and nothing should be wrong, right?
My model looks like this:

```
App.Box = DS.Model.extend({
  enabled: DS.attr('boolean'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date'),

  boxMeters: DS.hasMany('App.BoxMeter')
});
```

The App.BoxMeter is very similar, but they key thing is that all of this worked before I upgraded to 1.0.0.

I get a couple of errors thrown in my face. They are:

```
Assertion failed: No model was found for 'App.Box' ember.js?body=1:394

Error while loading route: TypeError {} ember.js?body=1:394

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined
```

none of which makes any sense for me. I have looked over the routes and models countless times, and this is just .. weird! How should I tackle this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
boxMeters: DS.hasMany('App.BoxMeter')
```

with:

```
boxMeters: DS.hasMany('boxMeter')
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I can't find where it is referenced in the documentation? Can you link to where you found this?

Comment: I found this pull request to update the Transition docs https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1159

Comment: Its also in the Ember Data Beta 2 release blog post: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/09/04/ember-data-1-0-beta-2-released.html