# Emberjs - How to set model of different route when using named outlets

Tags: ember.js

I'm loading data from XboxLive and other services in my ApplicationRoute and want to display that information using named outlets.  I used this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463958/how-to-use-multiple-models-with-a-single-route-in-emberjs-ember-data/16465291#16465291) as a guide, but it's not working.

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sandalsoft/7xHfp/

In the `ApplicationRoute`, the `model` hook loads data from online services.  This data is accessible as `model.xbox`, `model.facebook`, etc...  `setupController` then sets the `content` of the `XboxprofileController` to `model.xbox`.

This doesn't work when I call `App.Xboxprofile.find()` (returns a promise), but it does work when I call `App.Xboxprofile.findSimple()` (returns a simple object).  Why doesn't this work when find() has any kind of asynchrony?  Am I missing something simple, or is this not the right way to architect this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @alexspeller in #emberjs for the answer.

I mistakenly thought model.xbox was a promise.  It's an object.  When I changed my model hook to use RSVP.hash() it worked perfectly:

```
model: function(controller)
        var allModels = Em.RSVP.hash({
            xbox: App.Xboxprofile.find('major nelson'),

        }).then(function(hash) {
            return Em.RSVP.hash(hash);
        });

        return allModels;
    },
```