# How can I make this Ember's {{render}} helper inject the given model into the controller?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I know I must be missing something, but I created a simple test to exercise the use of the `{{render "viewName" model}}` helper and I'm having trouble with it.

It works well except that in the view's controller I don't have access to a model property as indicated by the Ember documentation. Instead the controller's model property remains undefined.

Here is the fiddle that shows the issue:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/misiyaki/6/edit

As you can see I tested the model in the index template, and it works well. But when the `ViewAView` is rendered, the associated `ViewAController` does not have the specified model set in it. I tested it in the view's init method and it is not set there either. It is as if I had not specified any models in the helper.

What am I missing?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the model's referred to as model within the template, not `testModel` that was just the type of model you wanted the store to find.

Additionally the controller needs to be an `ObjectController` if it's being backed an object.

```
App.ViewAController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/misiyaki/7/edit

Comment: Oh I see, but according to the docs (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/) I can specify which model I want to use with the `{{render}}` helper, right? It refers to `{{render "author" author}}`, indicating the model by name. That's what I'm trying to do.. In this case I want to use a model different from the route's model. I just didn't define two of them, and was trying to call the same by name as the doc seems to suggest. Is this possible at all? To be in a context with model `A` and invoke the `{{render}}` helper to render `viewX` with model `B`?

Comment: OK, I understood this now. The model needs to be available in the context, which sucks. But with the workaround provided by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463958/how-to-use-multiple-models-with-a-single-route-in-emberjs-ember-data it is possible to have multiple, unrelated models in the same context so one could be passed to render. Thanks!